# Dynatrace New Users, Total Users

Tags: dynatrace

I am new at dynatrace and I can see i can pull data via sql.   I have tried this to create an info block on the dynatrace dashboard.

I tried this for total users

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersession WHERE useraction.application='MY_APP' and newUser IS false
```

And tried this for new users

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersession WHERE useraction.application='MY_APP' and newUser IS true
```

But the numbers that I am getting is way low.  Anyone here can give me a hint to get the new users and total users from dynatrace.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your USQL statements will actually count the number of sessions, not users. So you would rather use "COUNT(DISTINCT userId)" or similar to not count users multiple times.

However this will actually return even lower numbers as usually users have multiple sessions over time.

For the too low count I would look at the timeframe that you have selected in the Dashboard, as that is applied as part of the query always.

See https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/real-user-monitoring/how-to-use-real-user-monitoring/cross-application-user-session-analytics/custom-queries-segmentation-and-aggregation-of-session-data/ for the official documentation.